# Function not running on phones with API level > 20

Tags: java, android

I am trying to execute a function that orders the hours loaded inside a multidimensional array. The function works great in the emulator and in phones with an API less than 20, but when running it on phones with an API greater than 20, the function does not run correctly.

My function:

```
 public int[] ordenarLlaves(String hora[][]){
    int indx[] = new int[hora.length];
    String aux[] = new String[hora.length];
    for(int i = 0; i < hora.length;i++){
        if(hora[i][1].length() != 0)
            aux[i] = hora[i][1];
    }
    List<Date> list = convertirHoras(aux);
    Collections.sort(list, new Comparator<Date>(){
        @Override
        public int compare(Date o1, Date o2) {
            return o1.compareTo(o2);
        }
    });
    for(int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++){
        for (int h = 0; h < aux.length; h++) {
            if (list.get(i).compareTo(convertirHora(aux[h])) == 0) {
                indx[i] = h;
            }
        }
    }
    return indx;
  }
```

Other function that I use:

```
 public Date convertirHora(String hora){
    Date hor = new Date();
    String aux = "";
    try{
        SimpleDateFormat formato = new SimpleDateFormat("h:mm a");
        for(int c = 0; c < hora.length(); c++){
            aux += Character.toString(hora.charAt(c));
            if(aux.charAt(c) == 'M'){break;}
        }
        hor = formato.parse(hora);
    }catch(ParseException e){}
    return hor;
}
```

How it works in the android emulator:

[image]

In phone (ANDROID 5.0, API 21)

[image]

I think, is something with Date class, but I'm not sure... :(

UPDATE: Now, I´m running the app in a cellphone with ANDROID 4.4.2, API 19. Works nice...

[image]

Comment: emulator is running API 24?

Comment: Yes @android_Muncher, only work in emulator, but with real phones, nope

Comment: I uploaded another capture... see what I mean @android_Muncher

Comment: are you using import java.text.SimpleDateFormat; ?

Comment: yea, to use 12 hours format @android_Muncher

Comment: Also, with SimpleDateFormat I transform Strings to Date type

Comment: is that the import statement that you are using ?

Comment: Yes..... I´m using it.

Comment: Run the debugger against the code. Don't trust the UI to tell you the values